# Filebeat and Kafka: Client has run out of available brokers to talk to

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, filebeat

I have two servers, lets name them `server1` and `server2`.

On `server1` I have a `docker` container with `Kafka` running. Port of `Kafka` Broker and Zookeeper are mapped to the host.

On `server2` I want to install `Filebeat` which sends some log messages to `Kafka` on `server1`. It seems that it can establish the connection to the broker...

```
[publisher_pipeline_output]        pipeline/output.go:143        Connecting to kafka(server1:9092)
[publisher_pipeline_output]        pipeline/output.go:151        Connection to kafka(server1:9092) established
```

...but the actual sending of the message fails with the error message:

```
[kafka] kafka/client.go:317     Kafka (topic=sample-topic): kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
```

I've also tried to run the `kafka-producer-console` (also in a docker) from my `server2` and that actually worked! The only difference is that my `Filebeat` does not run in a `docker` container but directly on `server2`.

So what did I forget? Any idea how to further debug the issue?

As `ADVERTISED_HOST` when running the container I did use the `server1` hostname.

**For clarification:**
I'm using `KAfka` from `spotify/kafka` (https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/kafka) and run it like that:

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --name kafka --env ADVERTISED_HOST=server1 --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
```

my `Filebeat` config looks like this:

```
output.kafka:
  hosts: ["server1:9092"]
  topic: 'sample-topic'
  partition.round_robin:
    reachable_only: false

  required_acks: 1
  compression: gzip
  max_message_bytes: 1000000
```

Comment: Added now. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Port of Kafka Broker and Zookeeper are mapped to the host

For Kafka, you need more than just a port mapping. You also need to set up the advertised listener address (advertised *host* is a deprecated property) to be the external hostname/ip of the server where the container is running in order to access it from another machine. You also need the listeners address to 0.0.0.0

> Filebeat does not run in a docker container but directly on server2

Shouldn't matter

If the console producer works from the other machine, then you would expect any other Kafka client to work as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe for clarification, I'm using Spotify/KAFKA from https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/kafka which says that you should set ADVERTISED_HOST and ADVERTISED_PORT. Nevertheless - if that would be the issue - should my test using the kafka-console-producer on server2 not also fail?

Comment: The Spotify container has not been maintained in years. I suggest you use separate, newer Kafka and Zookeeper containers

Comment: I didn't find the issue for this problem but I followed you advice and used a different docker image (from wurstmeister) which works out-of-the-box. Thanks for the advice!